# The JS file is not working as i want it to after copying it in to the HTML file. below is the code along with the code in my js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the HTML file where I've linked the file `news.js`.
The click methods which I've written aren't working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>NEWS</title>
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="articles container">

      <div class="article current">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">FLIGHT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">Embraer adds third Legacy 500 prototype to flight test campaign</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 23</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Embraer adds third Legacy 500 prototype to flight test campaign</h1>
            <p>The third Legacy 500 has joined Embraer's flight test programme aimed at delivering the midsize business jet in 2014. The airtcraft, serial number 003...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
            <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">AW business aviation</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">Flying the Gulfstream G650</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Flying the Gulfstream G650</h1>
            <p>Gulfstream is turning up the heat in the large-cabin business aircraft competition with its new G650 flagship, the largest, fastest, farthest-ranging...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">FLIGHT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">New retirements cut RAF VC10 fleet to four</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>New retirements cut RAF VC10 fleet to four</h1>
            <p>The UK Royal Air Force has retired another two of its Vickers VC10 tankers, with the pair's departure reducing its inventory of the Rolls-Royce...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">FLIGHT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">Virgin can deliver more value for Delta than for SIA: Bastian</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Jul 17</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Virgin can deliver more value for Delta than for SIA: Bastian</h1>
            <p>Delta Air Lines president Ed Bastian is confident that the carrier can extract far more value from its shareholding in Virgin Atlantic compared with...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">AW Defense</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">Freedom Experiences Two More Power Outages</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Freedom Experiences Two More Power Outages</h1>
            <p>The Littoral Combat Ship (LCS-1) USS Freedom’s first overseas deployment to Southeast Asia has been marred by two more power outages...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article">
        <div class="item row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="source">FLIGHT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="title">FedEx to acquire up to 30 United 757s</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>FedEx to acquire up to 30 United 757s</h1>
            <p>United Airlines is to sell up to 30 Boeing 757s to freight operator FedEx Express, with deliveries of the twinjets set to start this year.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="news.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

news.js file

```
var main = function() {
  $('.article').click(function() {
    $('.article').removeClass('current');
     $('.description').hide();
    $(this).addClass('.current);
        $(this).children('.description').show();

    $(document).keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which === 111);{
        $('.current).children('.description').toggle();
        }
    });

  });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: i want it to toggle between multiple news articles using a keypress news articles

Comment: finally figured. the site address was this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>. i was using the same without the https and it was showing an error while loading as file:/// which in my opinion was trying to read on the local machine. thank you all for your comments cuz they helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, first `main` is a function so add parenthesis after it. Your js has missing quotes:

Here...................................v (also you don't need the period when adding a class)

```
$(this).addClass('.current);
```

and here....v

```
$('.current).children('.description').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood it well this may help you:

```
/*global alert,jQuery*/
(function ($, window, document) {
  'use strict';

  $(function () {
    var $articles = $("div.article");

    $articles.on('click', function () {
      var $me = $(this);

      if (!$me.hasClass('current')) {
        $('div.article.current').removeClass('current');
        $me.addClass('current');
      }
    });

  });
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

and with css:

```
div.article div.description {
  display: none;
}

div.article.current div.description {
  display: block;
}
```

no need to do toggle visibility of div.description element using javascript.

Comment: Thanks Sid, i'm going to try it.